# DB2 query results in Hex format -- Need Character/String

Tags: db2, db2-400

I have a query that I can run on a DB2 table using my python SQL tester, and it returns the string values I'm looking for.
However, when I run it directly on my database it returns a hex value.  Any help in getting the results as a character string would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the field definition:

```
ORCTL      CCDATA         243      A   14  256 Order Control File Data
```

My query on the iSeries is:

```
select ccdata from ORCTL where ccctlk = 'BUYRAK'
```

Comment: Is this one resolved? What is the solution? I have a question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265732/from-hex-value-to-ebcdic-in-db2-for-iseries?noredirect=1#comment83517021_48265732

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your query, you can cast a string with another CCSID, eg :

```
select cast(ccdata as char(14) CCSID 37) from ORCTL where ccctlk = 'BUYRAK'
```

Comment: The same solution is not working here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265732/from-hex-value-to-ebcdic-in-db2-for-iseries

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it isn't returning hex...

Rather it's returning EBCDIC.

Your column is probably tagged with CCSID 65535, which tells the system not to translate it.

The right way to fix this issue, is to make sure the column is tagged with the appropriate CCSID; for example, 37 for US English.

The alternative, is to look for a "force translate" option in the settings of driver you're using.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  This is a table on our AS/400 so I can't really change the column.  Is there a way in DB2 to "CAST" this value into readable text?