# DB2 Concatenation not working in Informatica

Tags: db2, informatica, db2-400

I am using below query for DB2 database in SQ of a mapping and sending the records to a csv target:

```
SELECT FIELD1||':'||FIELD2 FROM LIBRARY.FILE
```

But its returning some hexadecimal value though it is returning correct number of records.
Even the above query is working fine in Squrrel.

But when I am not using the separator it is working fine (Below query):

```
SELECT FIELD1||FIELD2 FROM LIBRARY.FILE
```

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Check the CCSID of the user of the job. The CCSID of FIELD1 and FIELD2 are different from the string ':'. The FIELD1/2 CCSID come from the database, and I think the ':' comes from the CCSID of the job. If they are different, DB2 returns the result of the concatenation in EBCDIC.  Cast your ':' with the same CCSID as the FIELD1:

```
cast(':' as char(1) CCSID XXXX)
```

See [DB2 query results in Hex format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40741310/939484)

Answer (score 0):

and if you use

```
select field1 concat ':' concat field2 from yourlib.yourtable
```

OR

```
select concat(field1, concat(':', field2)) from yourlib.yourtable
```

NB: on AS400 you have a tool for export you table on IFS nammed CPYTOIMPF

example :

```
CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(yourlib/yourtable) TOSTMF('/yourIFSdir/outputfile.txt') STMFCODPAG(*PCASCII) RCDDLM(':')
```