# From Hex Value to EBCDIC in DB2 for iSeries

Tags: db2, db2-400

I have HEX data like this (F9F9F9F9) returned from a query. When I checked from IBM link : 
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS2MB5_14.1.0/com.ibm.xlf141.bg.doc/language_ref/asciit.html

F9 = 9 and F9 = 9

Here I should get result as 9999

I jhave around 1000 hex records like this in a table.

How can I convert this hex values to it corrsponding EBCDIC ?

I tried like :

```
  select cast(col char(2) as codebase(37)) from table
```

How ever, its not working.
      THis link is also not working: I'm not sure if its a cobol code or DB2 script. : http://www.ibmmainframeforum.com/db2/topic8785.html

Please help.Thanks.

Comment: Your columns has a particular CCSID, see [DB2 query results in Hex format — Need Character/String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727461/db2-query-results-in-hex-format-need-character-string/40741310#40741310)

Comment: I have written this like this : select cast(C as char(4) CCSID 37) from Table . However, its not showing EBCDIC. Its still returning me the HEX. Note: It looks like in Iseries Its not working. I think, the iSeries version I'm using is 7.2 .  Any other solution please?

Comment: What's the data type of the column you're selecting?

Comment: The original type is decimal(11,2) ; I'm converting this to HEX and from hex I'm trying to convert this (HEX) into Char

Comment: Why don't you convert the value to CHAR directly? I presume the `HEX()` function does an implicit cast to CHAR anyway?

Comment: Those chars are looking like  junks to me. So, when I'll convert that to HEX and then to EBCDIC , then it will be good looking (and the desired values). Is there any ways , where I can convert junk looking chars directly to EBCDIC?

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(col char(2) as codebase(37)) from table
```

Correct Syntax.

```
select cast(col as char(2) ccsid 37) as col from table
```

Generally you don't want to do this over and over so maybe just alter the table.

```
ALTER TABLE mylib/Z1 ALTER COLUMN JOJOB SET DATA TYPE CHARACTER ( 
10) CCSID 37 NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT
```

Or create a view over the table for read only data and read from the view.

```
create view tablev as 
select cast(col as char(2) ccsid 37) as col from table
```